# Wifi stopped working after system update 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

The wifi on my Dell XPS 13 stopped working yesterday. It connects, and drops the connection a few seconds later. It was working before, the only thing I can think of that happened was a routine system update.

This is the chipset:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
```

Any ideas?

Edit: This seems to have been a hardware problem, replacing the wifi-card solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to Internet via LAN cable and run `apt-get -f install` to fix anything went wrong.
2. Check **Additional Drivers** for drivers and if you find it already activated; deactivate and activate again.

Comment: Thanks, but no change.